# Sem retorno Json para Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, json

Não recebo o retorno do Json no Ajax. Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Ajax.js

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url: "crud/insere.php",
data: dados,
success: function(data) {

    var objeto = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(objeto.id);

 }
 });
 return false;
```

insere.php

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$telefone1 = $_POST['telefone1'];
$operadora1 = $_POST['operadora1'];
$telefone2 = $_POST['telefone2'];
$operadora2 = $_POST['operadora2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cidade = $_POST['idCidade'];
$observacao = $_POST['obs'];
$dataCadastro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if(empty($cidade)){
   $cidade = '0';
}

 $select = "INSERT INTO Cliente(nome, telefone1, telefone2, operadora1,   operadora2, 
       email, idCidade, observacao, dataCadastro) 
       VALUES ('$nome', '$telefone1', '$telefone2', '$operadora1',     '$operadora2', '$email', '$cidade','$observacao', '$dataCadastro')";
 $conexao = conexao();           
 $PDO=$conexao->prepare($select);
 $PDO->execute();

 $select = "SELECT id FROM Cliente WHERE email='$email'";
 $PDO=$conexao->prepare($select);
 $PDO->execute();
 $obj = $PDO -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 $arr = array('id' => $obj->id);
 echo json_encode($arr);insira o código aqui
```

Código Completo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O registro está sendo inserido no banco? O PHP está apresentando algum erro? A variável "dados" do Javascript está sendo preenchida com os dados do form corretamente? Precisamos de mais detalhes pra ajudar.

Uma boa ferramenta pra testar APIs é o POSTMAN, plugin para o Google Chrome. Nele você simula a chamada HTTP (Ajax) e visualiza o retorno do servidor.

Comment: Os registros estão gravando no banco, no console não apresenta nenhum erro. Acredito que está preenchendo certo, você pode conferir na imagem do fonte completo. Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Só olhando o código não consegui pensar em nada. O que sugiro é instalar o POSTMAN e simular a chamada. Você pode até debugar o código no processo.

Comment: Parece que o endereço do plugin POSTMAN está fora, não carrega aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando o código rapidamente eu vi algo que se estiver presente no código que vc está rodando realmente poderá ser a causa. É a última linha:

```
echo json_encode($arr);insira o código aqui
```

apague após o ;

caso isso  não esteja presente no código faça assim:

1o mude o código para isto:

```
alert('antes ajax'); //ou console.log, como preferir
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "crud/insere.php",
    data: dados,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('funcao success');
        var objeto = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(objeto.id);

     }
 });
 return false;
```

para saber se há algum erro de sintaxe ou se o código nem chega a ser executado. Caso saiba usar, seria melhor vc usasse o debugger do navegador ao invés dos alerts ou console.log.

Depois verifique o log do apache ou do seu servidor http. Para o apache costuma estar em /var/log/apache/error.log. Veja se tem algum erro de php lá.

após isso, caso vc não use algum debugger com o php para ver onde está falhando, coloque alguns echos em várias partes do código mesmo que fique mal na tela para ver onde está a linha que o erro ocorre.

Se isto não for suficiente pra vc ver onde está o erro, quando descobrir a linha, edite a pergunta com a parte do código onde está o erro e continuarei a lhe auxiliar.

Comment: Não fazia parte do código: echo json_encode($arr);insira o código aqui 

Implementei a linha que você sugeriu, e ele fez o alert('antes ajax') e alert('funcao success'), porém o alert(objeto.id) não fez.

Verificando os logs de erro, também não achei nada.

Estou achando impossível isso não funcionar. Você quer uma cópia do projeto para poder tentar me ajudar? O projeto é tranquilo, tem apenas esse fonte ai...

Comment: Acho que já sei o que é: retire a linha `var objeto = JSON.parse(data);` e use diretamente `alert(data.id);` acho que o JSON já está sendo passado diretamente e o parse não é necessário. Teste se isso é verdade pf.

Comment: e aí ? deu certo ?

Comment: Cara, deu certo, funcionando perfeitamente.
Obrigado pela ajuda! Abraços.

Comment: Que bom. Não esqueça de selecionar uma das respostas como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Nessa situação basta olhar o que a requisição ajax está retornando. Na pagina que faz a requisição vá em inspecionar elementos, network (rede) e veja o que está acontecendo com sua requisição (vai variar de navegador para navegador). Assim você vai ver se o erro na está na requisição, no servidor, ou no cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Só um detalhe a mais. Quando você informa dataType: 'json', o parâmetro do callback success já é um objeto json, ou seja, JSON.parse é desnecessário e pode gerar uma exception em alguns casos.

Seu código JS pode ser assim:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url: "crud/insere.php",
data: dados,
success: function(data) {
    alert('funcao success');
    alert(data.id);
 }
```

});

No seu arquivo PHP é **indispensável** incluir o header de json:

```
<?PHP
$data = /** seus dados **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Outra coisa importante é que o json_encode() só funciona com dados em UTF-8. Ou seja, se o seu arquivo php ou seus dados no banco estiver em ISO-8859-1, você precisa fazer antes um utf8_encode() em cada uma das strings.